# SciKit Classification Metric

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bigdata, data-science

I am running random forest and gradient boosting using sklearn on a classification problem.I got Classification Accuracy: 0.770 (0.048) 
what does the number in brackets mean?

```
models = []
models.append(('DT', DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 10,
               max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=2)))

models.append(('RF', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, criterion='gini', max_features='auto',min_samples_split=2)))

models.append(('XT', ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=500,max_features= 8,criterion= 'entropy',min_samples_split= 2,
                                          max_depth= 5, min_samples_leaf= 3)))

models.append(('GB', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.1,n_estimators=700, min_samples_split=2,min_samples_leaf=3,max_depth=4,
                                                max_features='sqrt',subsample=0.6,random_state=10)))

models.append(('ADB', AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=500,learning_rate=0.2,random_state=0)))

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, x_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Comment: can you show us the code that you are running to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

You are running 10-fold cross validation.

The number in brackets is the standard deviation in the model accuracy over all 10 folds. It comes from the following line of code:

```
msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
```